# This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or by calling the model on a batch of data. Why and how?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

I've been building a Image Captioning Deep Learning Model where I have 2 custom keras layers and 1 custom keras model. When I try to get the summary of the model using summary(), it throws an error. The model has TransformerEncoderBlock, TransformerDecoderBlock (layers) and ImageCaptioningModel(Model).

```
class TransformerEncoderBlock(layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, embed_dim, dense_dim, num_heads, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.embed_dim = embed_dim
    self.dense_dim = dense_dim
    self.num_heads = num_heads
    self.attention_1 = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        num_heads = num_heads, key_dim = embed_dim, dropout = 0.0
    )
    self.layernorm_1 = layers.LayerNormalization()
    self.layernorm_2 = layers.LayerNormalization()
    self.dense_1 = layers.Dense(embed_dim, activation = "relu")

  def call(self, inputs, training, mask = None):
    inputs = self.layernorm_1(inputs)
    inputs = self.dense_1(inputs)
    attention_output_1 = self.attention_1(
        query = inputs,
        value = inputs,
        key = inputs,
        attention_mask = None,
        training = training,
    )
    out_1 = self.layernorm_2(inputs + attention_output_1)
    return out_1

  def get_config(self):
    config = super(TransformerEncoderBlock, self).get_config()
    config.update({
        "embed_dim":self.embed_dim,
        "dense_dim":self.dense_dim,
        "num_heads":self.num_heads,
        "attention_1":self.attention_1,
        "layernorm_1":self.layernorm_1,
        "layernorm_2":self.layernorm_2,
        "dense_1":self.dense_1
    })
    return config
```

```
class PositionalEmbedding(layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, sequence_length, vocab_size, embed_dim, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.token_embeddings = layers.Embedding(
        input_dim = vocab_size, output_dim = embed_dim
    )
    self.position_embeddings = layers.Embedding(
        input_dim = sequence_length, output_dim = embed_dim
    )
    self.sequence_length = sequence_length
    self.vocab_size = vocab_size
    self.embed_dim = embed_dim
    self.embed_scale = tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(embed_dim, tf.float32))

  def call(self, inputs):
    length = tf.shape(inputs)[-1]
    positions = tf.range(start = 0, limit = length, delta = 1)
    embedded_tokens = self.token_embeddings(inputs)
    embedded_tokens = embedded_tokens *  self.embed_scale
    embedded_positions = self.position_embeddings(positions)
    return embedded_tokens + embedded_positions

  def get_config(self):
    config = super(PositionalEmbedding, self).get_config()
    config.update({
        "token_embeddings":self.token_embeddings,
        "position_embeddings":self.position_embeddings,
        "sequence_length":self.sequence_length,
        "vocab_size":self.vocab_size,
        "embed_dim":self.embed_dim,
        "embed_scale":self.embed_scale
    })
    return config

  def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask = None):
    return tf.math.not_equal(inputs, 0)
```

```
class TransformerDecoderBlock(layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, embed_dim, ff_dim, num_heads, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.embed_dim = embed_dim
    self.ff_dim = ff_dim
    self.num_heads = num_heads
    self.attention_1 = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        num_heads = num_heads, key_dim = embed_dim, dropout = 0.1
    )
    self.attention_2 = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        num_heads = num_heads, key_dim = embed_dim, dropout = 0.1
    )
    self.attention_3 = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        num_heads = num_heads, key_dim = embed_dim, dropout = 0.1
    )
    self.attention_4 = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        num_heads = num_heads, key_dim = embed_dim, dropout = 0.1
    )

    self.ffn_layer_1 = layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation = "relu")
    self.ffn_layer_2 = layers.Dense(embed_dim)

    self.layernorm_1 = layers.LayerNormalization()
    self.layernorm_2 = layers.LayerNormalization()
    self.layernorm_3 = layers.LayerNormalization()
    self.layernorm_4 = layers.LayerNormalization()
    self.layernorm_5 = layers.LayerNormalization()

    self.embedding = PositionalEmbedding(
        embed_dim = EMBED_DIM, sequence_length = SEQ_LENGTH, vocab_size = VOCAB_SIZE
    )
    self.out = layers.Dense(VOCAB_SIZE, activation = "softmax")

    self.dropout_1 = layers.Dropout(0.3)
    self.dropout_2 = layers.Dropout(0.5)
    self.supports_masking = True

  def call(self, inputs, encoder_outputs, training, mask = None):
    inputs = self.embedding(inputs)
    causal_mask = self.get_causal_attention_mask(inputs)

    if mask is not None:
      padding_mask = tf.cast(mask[:,:,tf.newaxis], dtype = tf.int32)
      combined_mask = tf.cast(mask[:,tf.newaxis,:], dtype = tf.int32)
      combined_mask = tf.minimum(combined_mask, causal_mask)

    attention_output_1 = self.attention_1(
        query = inputs,
        value = inputs,
        key = inputs,
        attention_mask = combined_mask,
        training = training,
    )
    out_1 = self.layernorm_1(inputs + attention_output_1)

    attention_output_2 = self.attention_2(
        query = out_1,
        value = encoder_outputs,
        key = encoder_outputs,
        attention_mask = padding_mask,
        training = training,
    )
    out_2 = self.layernorm_2(out_1 + attention_output_2)

    attention_output_3 = self.attention_3(
        query = out_2,
        value = out_2,
        key = out_2,
        attention_mask = causal_mask,
        training = training,
    )
    out_3 = self.layernorm_3(out_2 + attention_output_3)

    ffn_out = self.ffn_layer_1(out_2)
    ffn_out = self.dropout_1(ffn_out, training = training)
    ffn_out = self.ffn_layer_2(ffn_out)

    ffn_out = self.layernorm_4(ffn_out + out_3, training = training)
    ffn_out = self.dropout_2(ffn_out, training = training)

    attention_output_4 = self.attention_4(
        query = ffn_out,
        value = ffn_out,
        key = ffn_out,
        attention_mask = causal_mask,
        training = training,
    )

    ffn_out = self.layernorm_5(ffn_out + attention_output_4)
    preds = self.out(ffn_out)
    return preds

  def get_config(self):
    config = super(TransformerDecoderBlock, self).get_config()
    config.update({
        "embed_dim":self.embed_dim,
        "ff_dim":self.ff_dim,
        "num_heads":self.num_heads,
        "attention_1":self.attention_1,
        "attention_2":self.attention_2,
        "attention_3":self.attention_3,
        "attention_4":self.attention_4,
        "ffn_layer_1":self.ffn_layer_1,
        "ffn_layer_2":self.ffn_layer_2,
        "layernorm_1":self.layernorm_1,
        "layernorm_2":self.layernorm_2,
        "layernorm_3":self.layernorm_3,
        "layernorm_4":self.layernorm_4,
        "layernorm_5":self.layernorm_5,
        "embedding":self.embedding,
        "out":self.out,
        "dropout_1":self.dropout_1,
        "dropout_2":self.dropout_2,
        "supports_masking":self.supports_masking,

    })
    return config

  def get_causal_attention_mask(self, inputs):
    input_shape = tf.shape(inputs)
    batch_size, sequence_length = input_shape[0], input_shape[1]
    i = tf.range(sequence_length)[:, tf.newaxis]
    j = tf.range(sequence_length)
    mask = tf.cast(i >= j, dtype = "int32")
    mask = tf.reshape(mask, (1, input_shape[1], input_shape[1]))
    mult = tf.concat(
        [tf.expand_dims(batch_size, -1), tf.constant([1,1], dtype = tf.int32)],
        axis = 0,
    )
    return tf.tile(mask, mult)
```

```
class ImageCaptioningModel(keras.Model):
  def __init__(self,cnn_model, encoder, decoder, num_captions_per_image=5, image_aug=None):
    super().__init__()
    self.encoder = encoder
    self.decoder = decoder
    self.image_aug = image_aug
    self.cnn_model = cnn_model
    self.loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name = "loss")
    self.acc_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name = "accuracy")
    self.num_captions_per_image = num_captions_per_image

  def config(self):
    config = super(ImageCaptioningModel, self).get_config()
    config.update({
        "encoder":self.encoder,
        "decoder":self.decoder,
        "image_aug":self.image_aug,
        "cnn_model":self.cnn_model,
        "loss_tracker":self.loss_tracker,
        "acc_tracker":self.acc_tracker,
        "num_captions_per_image":self.num_captions_per_image
    })
    return config

  def calculate_loss(self, y_true, y_pred, mask):
    loss = self.loss(y_true, y_pred)
    mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype = loss.dtype)
    loss *= mask
    return tf.reduce_sum(loss) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)

  def calculate_accuracy(self, y_true, y_pred, mask):
    accuracy = tf.equal(y_true, tf.argmax(y_pred, axis = 2))
    accuracy = tf.math.logical_and(mask, accuracy)
    accuracy = tf.cast(accuracy, dtype = tf.float32)
    mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype = tf.float32)
    return tf.reduce_sum(accuracy) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)

  def _compute_caption_loss_acc(self, img_embed, batch_seq, training = True):
    encoder_out = self.encoder(img_embed, training = training)
    batch_seq_inp = batch_seq[:,:-1]
    batch_seq_true = batch_seq[:,1:]
    mask = tf.math.not_equal(batch_seq_true,0)
    batch_seq_pred = self.decoder(
        batch_seq_inp, encoder_out, training = training, mask = mask
    )
    loss = self.calculate_loss(batch_seq_true, batch_seq_pred, mask)
    acc = self.calculate_accuracy(batch_seq_true, batch_seq_pred, mask)
    return loss, acc

  def train_step(self, batch_data):
    batch_img, batch_seq = batch_data
    batch_loss = 0
    batch_acc = 0
    if self.image_aug:
      batch_img = self.image_aug(batch_img)
    img_embed = self.cnn_model(batch_img)

    for i in range(self.num_captions_per_image):
      with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss, acc = self._compute_caption_loss_acc(img_embed, batch_seq[:,i,:], training = True)
        batch_loss += loss
        batch_acc += acc

      train_weights = (
          self.encoder.trainable_variables + self.decoder.trainable_variables
      )

      grads = tape.gradient(loss, train_weights)
      self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, train_weights))

    batch_acc /= float(self.num_captions_per_image)
    self.loss_tracker.update_state(batch_loss)
    self.acc_tracker.update_state(batch_acc)

    return {"loss" : self.loss_tracker.result(), "Accuracy" : self.acc_tracker.result()}

  def test_step(self, batch_data):
    batch_img, batch_seq = batch_data
    batch_loss = 0
    batch_acc = 0
    img_embed = self.cnn_model(batch_img)

    for i in range(self.num_captions_per_image):
      loss, acc = self._compute_caption_loss_acc(img_embed, batch_seq[:,1,:], training = False)
      batch_loss += loss
      batch_acc += acc
    batch_acc /= float(self.num_captions_per_image)

    self.loss_tracker.update_state(batch_loss)
    self.acc_tracker.update_state(batch_acc)

    return {"loss" : self.loss_tracker.result(), "acc" : self.acc_tracker.result()}

  @property
  def metrics(self):
    return [self.loss_tracker, self.acc_tracker]
```

```
cnn_model = get_cnn_model()
encoder = TransformerEncoderBlock(embed_dim=EMBED_DIM, dense_dim=FF_DIM, num_heads=1)
decoder = TransformerDecoderBlock(embed_dim=EMBED_DIM, ff_dim=FF_DIM, num_heads=2)
caption_model = ImageCaptioningModel(
    cnn_model=cnn_model, encoder=encoder, decoder=decoder,image_aug=image_augmentation
)
```

The model gets compiled and even completed Training using .fit() but when I run

```
caption_model.summary()
```

It throws the following error.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in summary(self, line_length, positions, print_fn, expand_nested, show_trainable, layer_range)
   3227         """
   3228         if not self.built:
-> 3229             raise ValueError(
   3230                 "This model has not yet been built. "
   3231                 "Build the model first by calling `build()` or by calling "

ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or by calling the model on a batch of data.
```

```
BATCH_SIZE = 12 #64
# Image Size
IMAGE_SIZE = (299,299)
# Number of epochs
EPOCHS = 30
# Vocabulary size
VOCAB_SIZE = 15000
# Fixed length for any sequence
SEQ_LENGTH = 70
# Dimension for Image embeddings and tokens embeddings
EMBED_DIM = 64 #512 #720
# layer units in feed forward network
FF_DIM = 64 #512 #720
```

these are my input values

Kindly help me with a solution !

Answer (score 1):

The `build()` method is responsible for creating the model's variables and defining the model's architecture based on the input shapes. The `summary()` method can only be called after the model has been built.

Generic `built()` function is as follows:

```
def build(self, input_shape):
        image_shape, caption_shape = input_shape

        # Build the CNN model and get the output shape
        cnn_output_shape = self.cnn_model(image_shape)

        # Build the Encoder and specify the input shape
        self.encoder.build(cnn_output_shape)

        # Build the Decoder and specify the input shape
        # For the Decoder, the input shape is the concatenation of the CNN output and the caption_shape
        decoder_input_shape = cnn_output_shape[:-1] + (cnn_output_shape[-1] + caption_shape[-1],)
        self.decoder.build(decoder_input_shape)

        # Set `built` to True to mark that the model is built
        self.built = True


# Call the build() method with the input shapes
caption_model.build(input_shape=(image_shape, caption_shape))

caption_model.summary()
```

Include this function inside `ImageCaptioningModel()` instance.

Remember to pass input_shape as per your model. After that `model.summary()` should work.

Comment: Thanks but it throws an error
image_shape = (BATCH_SIZE,) + IMAGE_SIZE + (3,)
caption_shape = (BATCH_SIZE, SEQ_LENGTH)
combine_shape = (image_shape, caption_shape)
caption_model.build(input_shape=(combine_shape))

Layer "model" expects 1 input(s), but it received 4 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=12>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=299>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=299>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=3>]

Comment: It is expecting input as a single tuple, concatenating into a single tuple might do the job
`image_shape = (BATCH_SIZE,) + IMAGE_SIZE`
`caption_shape = (BATCH_SIZE, SEQ_LENGTH)`
`combine_shape = [image_shape, caption_shape]`

`caption_model.build(input_shape=combine_shape)`
`